# Como agregar un 0 a la izquierda al valor de un campo en oracle con LPAD?

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente consulta, donde el campo `ENTIDAD_REC` es de tipo varchar me parece y tiene valores como estos 012, 003, 011.

Lo que hago es mostrar esa consulta en un archivo .csv  y ese campo muestra únicamente los valores  12, 3, 11, NO muestra los ceros, y no se si es tema de como excel interprete la informacion,  hice la consulta usando `LPAD`, para añadir el "0", puse el nombre del campo, el numero de veces que quiero que salga el caracter , y el caracter

```
SELECT F.ID, F.NOMBRE, TO_CHAR(F.FECHA_INI,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(F.FECHA_REGISTRO,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(F.FECHA.CARGA,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_UNO,'fm9990.00'), TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_DOS,'fm9990.00'), LPAD(F.ENTIDAD_REC,1,'0')
FROM FACTURA F
WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR  F.ID =?1)
AND F.FECHA_INI &gt;= TO_DATE(?2 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND F.FECHA_INI &lt;= TO_DATE(?3 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

pero al abrir el archivo en excel el campo muestra el valor 0, y si cambio a `LPAD(F.ENTIDAD_REC,2,'0')`, el archivo muestra el valor 1, entonces ya no se como emplearlo para añadir el cero y muestre tal cual la informacion de la BD, como le ñuedo hacer?

Este es mi código para generar la descarga del archivo .csv

```
if(factList !=null) { 
response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv"); response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=archivo.csv"); 

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); out.write("ID,NOMBRE,FECHA_INI, FECHA_REGISTRO"); out.write("\n"); 
for(String factu: factList){ out.write(factu.toCSVRepresentation()); 
out.write("\n"); 
} 
out.flush();
 out.close(); }
else{
 log.info("Esta vacio"); } }catch(ControlException e){ throw new ControlException("Error", e); } }
```

Este es el.metodo

```
public String toCSV(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(getId()).append(“,”),builder.append(getFecInicio()).append(“,”),
. . . 
return builder.toString();
```

Comment: si excel ve solo numeros, entonces va a remover los 0 por defecto. El archivo csv tiene que tener esos campos entre comillas como si fueran texto para que se guarden los 0.

Comment: @gbianchi, actualize mi pregunta con el código que tengo para generar el .csv, en la línea out.write("ID,NOMBRE,FECHA_INI, FECHA_REGISTRO"); póngo el nombre de los campos que quiero mostrar, es aquí donde deben llevar las comillas?

Comment: no. en la funcion que arma el string que se graba, ahi es donde esos datos que vos queres como texto deben ir entre comillas.

Comment: Adentro del for tengo la línea que manda a llamar el método toCSVRepresentation que es con el que se llena el archivo,aquí deben de ir las comillas, pero como sería? Dejó el.codigo de ese método

Comment: Si pero el metodo no esta en la pregunta.. y solo hay que modificar ese metodo para que la salida sea diferente...

Comment: Sería en el .append(), como tengo las comas?

Comment: Porfa, aprende a formatear el codigo!!! mira [ask].. despues, deberia apendar delante y detras de lo que queres un "

Comment: Disculpa lo que pasa es que estoy en el móvil y no se visualiza los elementos para colocar bien el código, así es correcto                  
 builder.append("").append(getId()).append("").append(“,”), builder.append("").append(getFecInicio()).append("").append(“,”)

Comment: Tienes razón @gbianchi. No me había fijado bien en lo de csv, porque estaba desde el móvil. Borro respuesta!

Comment: Supongo que si.. pruebalo y nos dices...

Comment: Ya lo probé pero no hace nada, lo probé con comillas simple .apped(" ' ").append(getId()).append(" ' ").append(",") Y lo único que haces es mostrar en la cabecera el campo de está manera 'ID'